# Why doesn't this code print the encoded result correctly?

Tags: javascript, decode, encode

I'm pretty new to `JavaScript (JS)`, so this may be a simple fix.
 I was trying to make a program just to encode and decode some text, but it's not printing the output.
 Currently I only have the encoder part, so if anyone could help it would be appreciated!
Code:

```js
// Alphabet
    const alphabet ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",      
    "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", 
    "Z","`", "~", "1", "!", "2", "@", "3", "#", "4", "$", "6", "^", "7", "8", "*", "9", "(", 
    "0", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]", "\", "|", ";", ":", "'", ",", "<", ".", ">", 
    "/", "?"];

    function encode() {
        // variables
        var count = 0
        var count2 = 0
        var e = document.GetElementById("encode").value;
        let El = e.length;
        // Most important, contains encoded message
        const encoded = [];
        // Progresses through text
        while (count <= El) {
            count ++ 1;
        }
        while (alphabet[count2] != e.charAt(count2)) { 
            // Encodes Text into number value
            count2 ++ 1;
        }
        encoded.push(e.charAt(count2));
        document.write(encoded);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- UI (Will Update) -->
<h1 style = "color:blue">Enter text to be encoded here</h1>
<input id = "encode">
    <button onclick = "encode()">Encode</button>
<h1 style = "color:red">Enter text to be decoded here</h1>
<input id = "decode">
    <button onclick = "decode()">Decode</button>
<h2>Output:</h2>
    <p id = "output()"></p>
```

For some reason it's not printing, but that's likely a problem with the encoder.

Comment: `document.write` is discouraged, first of all, just so you know. Try just using a `console.log` or something. Try putting a lot of those logs all over the place so you can see where your code gets, where it maybe starts hanging (while loops are a dangerous thing) and then you can pinpoint where your issue is and debug that?

Comment: What are `count ++ 1` and `count ++ 2` supposed to do? They're invalid.

Comment: `const alphabet ["a", ...` should probably be `const alphabet = ["a", ...` - missing assignment operator

Answer (score 0):

In your alphabet array, you are not assigning properly, the `=` is missing also you have `"\"`, which breaks your code. If you want to have a string with a `\` in it you have to escape it with another `\`.
e.g. `"\\"`<-- this represents a sting comprising of a single `\`

Your first loop doesn't seem to be doing anything, and it's hard to tell the purpose of the second one as well, looks like it might cause an infinite loop.
I'm assuming you're trying to increment here `count ++ 1`. That should be `count += 1` or even `count++`

Since you have a tag to put the processed data you use that to show it instead of using `document.write`.